# Move rows based on values in X column with triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am looking for a solution that will move an entire row's content based on what is in the specified cell when the function is run on a trigger. I can accomplish this using the `onEdit(e)` within sheets, but when running a "regular" version, nothing happens. No errors.

I frequently use this type of functionality when a cell is edited, but for this specific sheet I need it to work when called (by trigger, manual, etc).

```js
function archive(){
  // assumes source data in sheet named Form Responses
  // target sheet of move to named ARCHIVE
  // Target col is B (3)
  // Target value is "TEST" to move to "ARCHIVE"

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var mainSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var r = mainSheet.getActiveRange();

if(r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() >= "TEST"){
   var row = r.getRow();
   var numColumns = mainSheet.getLastColumn();
   var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE");
   var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   mainSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true});
    mainSheet.deleteRow(row);
   }
}
```

When ran, nothing happens to the sheet. No error, no logs, etc.

Comment: Column B is 2. What do you mean `e.value >= "Test"`?

Comment: What do you expect that your function will do when the if condition returns false?